# Machine learning algorithm for predicting a quantitative value from many binary predictors

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm working on a project where I have many, many qualitative variables(700+) with binary values, and only a few are "true" or "1" for any given entry. There is also a single quantitative predictor. From these I'm trying to predict a quantitative value.

I'm considering using a simple linear regression model, but I'm not sure if that would be the best way to do it. What are some good algorithms that would suit this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is likely too general to be "answered" properly. Look into the algorithms available with scikit-learn. With the number of variables you have, I would tend to look at random forest methods.

Comment: Do look at scikit-learn. This might help : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html.

Comment: That looks really useful, thanks!

Comment: Another idea apart from random forest which is really suitable is to use Naive Bayes